# sending date in json object to restful ws

Tags: java, android, json, rest, jakarta-ee

I want to send a date (and other information ) in a json object from android Application to Restful WS

that's what i did in my android App.

```
        String date =  mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(mYear)) + "-" +  mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(mMonth+1)) + "-" +  mFormat.format(Double.valueOf(mDay)
                );
// so i will have somthing like date = "2016-03-30"

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.FRANCE);
        Date dateFin;
       dateFin= df.parse(date);
       jsonObject.put("datefin", dateFin);
```

in Web Service i am using hibernate for ORM with MySql and it work fin inserting the object into DB but the date field always NULL

a snap from the web service

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
public Response addOffer(Offers offer) throws IOException {
    offerService.addOffer(offer);
    return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(offer).build();

}
```

and here is the method addOffer.

```
public void addOffer(Offers offer) {

    // Offers f = new Offers("name","desc","category","market ",longitude,latitude,date);
    Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(offer);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

so any ideas why this happening and how to fix it ??

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the code in backend? and when you parse your JSON in your web service, date is not null? can you please paste webservice code to see how you are saving the date in hibernate?

Comment: i am not parsing the date the backend because i think it's done by the web service it self. i will put a snap from the web service.

Comment: yeah you would have to put some logging to see if the webservice is actually getting the date value.

Comment: i think it's getting it but in a bad format so it does not insert it to the DB, I posted some of the web service code

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code you just pasted. Post the code where the json you sent from your mobile client is parsed in web service? We will come to know if its expecting date to be in some format? or may be its not considering the date at all

Comment: i don't do any parsing just tell the web Service (jersey) that you expecting to have a jsonobject and i will convert it to a java object .                                    @Path("/offers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: this is the constructor of offers object.....Offers(String name, String description, String imageString,String category,
   double longitude,double latitude,String magasin,Date datefin,int userid)

Comment: @PuneetArora actually you right my web service receive the date as null , i just made a little logging

Comment: Perfect! That should help us

Comment: @PuneetArora thank you man you helped me in this.

Comment: No issues man! Glad its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end i found that if the date is not in this format

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

Restful WS refuse to consume it as a date so i change my code to

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.FRANCE);
```

of course i don't have time so it will be 00:00:00